# While Different Stack Sites Have Unique Meta Problems, Don't They Also Share Issues?

Tags: discussion

Every question or feature request I have made on a meta site would be applicable across all Stack X sites.

I am curious why meta is treated as unique per site.

Is there any value in having a centralized concept of meta?

I recognize other questions have pointed this out, but none have addressed the issue at the core. Do separate meta sites hurt the overall Stack concept?

Answer (score 4):

As an example, [Skeptics.SE](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com) has many meta-questions on the [nature of acceptable references](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=references).

A [discussion on the site-specific meta](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/958/citation-needed-header/1168#1168) lead to citation-needed post notices that other sites wouldn't need and would have been likely downvoted in the harsh environment of meta.stackoverflow.

So, yes, separate meta sites have separate purposes, and separate issues that need to be discussed within the confines of that community.

Comment: I understand. If someone uses Skeptic.SE exclusively, and posts a meta feature request that makes sense for all Stack sites, what happens?

Comment: In theory, the Stack Exchange Inc employees are monitoring it. However, if it gets a lot of upvotes and we see it is generically applicable, we encourage/help the user to post it on meta.stackoverflow for a wider audience to critique and upvote.

Comment: If this were code, that would be a fragile hack :). But in all seriousness, if the comments in the answer below are correct, Stack engineers are developing a Stack Meta which addresses the issue of a centralized Meta.

Comment: @gravidThoughts Yeah, Meta Stack Exchange will be along in [6-8 weeks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/223030).

Comment: @gravidThoughts: Sure, if efficiency of new feature requests is the property you most want to optimise. I suspect the community building aspects of meta outweigh the efficiency problems. (And I emphasize: Meta Stack Overflow is a harsh environment for the clueless.)

Comment: @michaelb958 LOL, should have included <sarcasm> with that. I almost took it for gospel until i clicked the link!

Comment: @gravidThoughts (It's actually been more like 12-16 months and counting. I really wish they'd hurry up.)

Comment: @Oddthinking What builds a community faster than allowing a user to know that there legitimate and unique input matters?

Answer (score 0):

Well your per-site Meta would be the place to go to discuss the topicness and scope of your site, which the rest of the network certainly wouldn't care about. So yes, there are site-specific issues that they need their own Meta for.

Comment: Changed the wording of the question, do all stack sites share common meta problems? Does separation hurt the ability to address this?

Comment: Yes, some issues are shared, but that's not much of a problem. Generally if there is something that is very applicable to every site that needs more attention than it can get on a per-site Meta, it'll get migrated here.

Comment: Meta SO is the central meta feature request repository? Or better stated, do you think the migration occurs with 100% efficiency? 80%? 40%?

Comment: Currently, yes. Until they release Meta Stack Exchange which will take over as the central Meta for issues that apply to everyone.

Comment: OK, was not aware a Meta Stack Exchange was in the works. If it is, then that answers my question. Centralized Stack X discussions and feature requests will have a formal process!

Comment: @gravidThoughts they arguably already have that formal process, though - here on Meta, no? Re "efficiency" of migrations, we have no way of knowing that number. But I think it's pretty safe to say that any great central suggestion is going to be moved to the main Meta eventually - seeing as Meta sites are supposed to be frequented by their moderators, and SE employees

Comment: @Pekka Fair enough.